# How to ignore different newline char with python filecmp

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have small script that compares files

```
import filecmp
filecmp.cmp(path1, path2)
```

This code returns `True` if files are similar
But it returns `False` in case when newline are different. `path1` have Linux newline and `path2` have Windows newline.
I want get `True` in case if files differs only with newline character.
Is it possible without editing files?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't have this capability. You'll need to convert the file format before doing the comparison.

Comment: I can convert files and it doesn't take a lot of time but it is extremely unwanted

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible to do with the `filecmp` module as it can only use `stat` to compare files and won't let you override the comparison.

You could do something with itertools as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280409/2537322):

```
from itertools import izip

def areFilesIdentical(filename1, filename2):
    with open(filename1, "rtU") as a:
        with open(filename2, "rtU") as b:
            # Note that "all" and "izip" are lazy
            # (will stop at the first line that's not identical)
            return all(myprint() and lineA == lineB
                       for lineA, lineB in izip(a, b))
```

Comment: If this helped you, please accept the answer (right under the downvote). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can strip the files of newlines and assign them to variables, and then compare those variables like so:

```
a = open('a.txt', 'r').read()
b = open('b.txt', 'r').read()
print(a==b)
```